# How to visualize tensorboard for tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I am a newbie and I have had some trouble in using tensorboard.
I stared Spyder in Anaconda prompt by

```
conda activate D:\Software\Anaconda\envs\tf
spyder
```

And this is my simple code in file trial.py

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = 2
b = 3
x = tf.add(a, b)
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer('./graphs')
print(writer)
```

Then I ran this code in spyder. I opened another Anaconda prompt and added this line

```
conda activate D:\Software\Anaconda\envs\tf
tensorboard --logdir=D:\Dung\Maytinh\Python\graphs --port 6006
```

I opened my Chrome and typed: http://localhost:6006/. The result was below:
[image]

I have tried many times and I could not understand where the error was. Some guides in the internet belong to tensorflow 1 and can not suit to handle. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs#graphs_of_tffunctions)

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = 2
b = 3

@tf.function
def func(x, y):
  return tf.add(a, b)

writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer('./graphs')

tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True, profiler=True)
z = func(a, b)
with writer.as_default():
  tf.summary.trace_export(
      name="trace",
      step=0,
      profiler_outdir='./graphs')
```

`tensorboard --logdir ./graphs`

Comment: First of all, thanks for helping me. After I fix as your code, the notification appeared: Graph visualization failed.
Error The graph is empty. This can happen when TensorFlow could not trace any graph. Please refer to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1961 for more information.

Comment: I only want the simplest example to understand tensorboard because document in the internet is terribly complicated for the beginner like me.

Comment: It does show the graph when I start `tensorboard` as shown. Try to restart tensor board..

Comment: Please upvote or accept if it is satisfctory.

Comment: Ok. I tried and it worked. Thank you a lot. I upvoted and accepted your answer.